# Enqueue script on specific WooCommerce template

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to enqueue a lightbox script on the WooCommerce page `content-single-product.php`.

I have tried the following via `functions.php`:

```
if(is_page_template( 'page-gallery.php' ) || is_page_template( 'content-single-product.php' )) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array(), '20150323', true );
}
```

The script loads correctly on `page-gallery.php`, but not on the WooCommerce single product page. I assume this method only works for my theme page templates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to delay the firing of your code, otherwise your conditionals will evaluate false (the request won't have been parsed yet). Use the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
function wpse_182357_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Your code
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_182357_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Update: Missed the root of the problem - `is_page_template()` only works for pages. Rather than checking if the current template file is `content-single-product.php`, check if the *request* is for a single product with [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular):

```
is_singular( 'product' );
```

Comment: I'm using the _S (Underscores) theme which already uses this method, so I'm guessing it's another issue.

Comment: Change `is_page_template( 'content-single-product.php' )` to `is_singular( 'product' )`